# SQL transform row value as column header with no value row

Tags: sql-server, excel-formula

I Have a table [dTaxCode] consisting of three fields

```
TaxCodeId, TaxCodeName ,DataAreaid
```

I need the rows transformed with filter on DataAreaId and the TaxCodeId as header.

Like:

```
SELECT TaxCodeId FROM dTaxCode where DataAreaId = 'xxx'
```

Expected result:

```
Tax1, Tax3, Tax4, ....
```

This is needed for a stored procedure with is called from excel to get the values as column header, which in return are to be used as input for a CUBEMEMBER formula.

I have tried pivot, xml and so on with no luck.

BR/ Jan

Answer (score 0):

From your question schema

```
CREATE TABLE #dTaxCode (
    TaxCodeId VARCHAR(20)
    ,TaxCodeName VARCHAR(20)
    ,DataAreaid VARCHAR(3)
    )

INSERT INTO #dTaxCode

SELECT 'Tax1'   ,'ABC'  ,'XXX'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tax2'   ,'BCD'  ,'YYY'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tax3'   ,'CDE'  ,'XXX'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Tax4'
    ,'DEF'
    ,'XXX'
```

And the query will be

```
SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + TaxCodeId
            FROM #dTaxCode
            WHERE DataAreaid = 'XXX'
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS TaxCodeId
```